# Pass URL parameter to frame

Tags: javascript

I have index.html with this content

```
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0" frameborder="0">
    <frame name="__main" src="https://mywebsite.com" noresize frameborder="0">
</frameset>
```

Trying to figure out how I can pass url parameters to the frame. E.g if I open url with ?param1=abc I want frame to open "https://mywebsite.com?param1=abc"

Is it possible with vanilla js?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this.

```
iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');

iframe.src = iframe.src + '?' + params;
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null

Comment: <script>
iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');

iframe.src = iframe.src + '?aaaa';
</script>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0" frameborder="0">
    <frame id='myIframe' name="__main" src="https://mywebsite.com" noresize frameborder="0">
</frameset>

Answer (score 0):

with jquery use it like this:

```
let src = 'https://mywebsite.com';
$('#your frame id').prop('src',src);
```